# Which possessive pronoun is correct?

Tags: pronouns, possessives

Could you advise - which is correct?

It's my and Louise's cat.
It's mine and Louise's cat.
It's Louise's and my cat.

Thanks

Comment: I agree with CipherBot. I'll add another possibility (I'm pretty sure it wasn't mentioned in that previous question). You could say, "It's my cat and Louise's" or "It's Louise's cat and mine."

Comment: Thanks Chasly. From the "duplicate" question - I take it that "It's Louise and I's cat" would be ok. That sounds wrong to me. I think the other answers indicate that "It's Louise's and my cat" is also fine.

Comment: If the sentence  "It's Louise and I's cat" is suggested then it is completely wrong!  However II would certainly accept "It's Louise's and my cat".